# How to solve Vnet error setting when joining SSIS IR to Vnet?

Tags: azure, ssis, vnet

I am trying to joining a ssis integration run time to a `Vnet` via `Azure Portal`, but when I try to validate the `Vnet` I get the following error

> Vnet setting error:
>   please remove love 'and here are listed a bunch of locks'

Now, the error sound pretty self-explanatory, but my since I am really new to networking in general and azure networking in particular, can anyone explain

- how can I remove the locks
- why I can't connet to a Vnet whose connected resources have locks ?

Thank you all in advance,

Liborio

Comment: You can try to remove the locks from virtual network panel---settings--locks in the Azure portal. There are `CanNotDelete` or `ReadOnly` lock level. If you want to update the resource, make sure there is no lock to prevent resources update. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources